# The entity type 'IdentityUserRole<string>' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor, asp.net-identity

i've the following code:

```
using MyBlazorApp.Server.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyBlazorApp.Server.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>, Guid>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }        

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .Property(e => e.firstName)
                .HasMaxLength(250);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .Property(e => e.lastName)
                .HasMaxLength(250);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .Property(e => e.isLdapLogin);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .Property(e => e.isMFAforce);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .Property(e => e.apiKey);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .Property(e => e.IsEnabled);

            //Seeding a  'Administrator' role to AspNetRoles table
            var arId = "dffc6dd5-b145-41e9-a861-c87ff673e9ca";
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(
                new IdentityRole
                {
                    Id = arId,
                    Name = "Admins",
                    NormalizedName = "ADMINS".ToUpper(),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = arId
                }
            ); ;
            var urId = "f8a527ac-d7f6-4d9d-aca6-46b2261b042b";
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(
                new IdentityRole
                {
                    Id = urId,
                    Name = "Users",
                    NormalizedName = "USERS".ToUpper(),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = urId
                }
            ); ;

            //a hasher to hash the password before seeding the user to the db
            var hasher = new PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>();

            //Seeding the Admin User to AspNetUsers table
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasData(
                new ApplicationUser
                {
                    Id = new Guid("6fbfb682-568c-4f5b-a298-85937ca4f7f3"), // primary key
                    UserName = "super.admin",
                    NormalizedUserName = "SUPER.ADMIN",
                    PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(null, "7ugVUczrm7"),
                    firstName = "Super",
                    lastName = "Admin",
                    Email = "super.admin@local.app",
                    NormalizedEmail = "SUPER.ADMIN@LOCAL.APP",
                    EmailConfirmed = true,
                    isMFAforce = 0,
                    isLdapLogin = 0
                }
            );

            List<IdentityUserRole<string>> UserRoles = new List<IdentityUserRole<string>>();
            UserRoles.Add(new IdentityUserRole<string>
            {
                RoleId = "dffc6dd5-b145-41e9-a861-c87ff673e9ca",
                UserId = "6fbfb682-568c-4f5b-a298-85937ca4f7f3"
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(UserRoles);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

    }
}
```

When i hit the command `dotnet ef migrations add IntitialMigration` i get the following error: **The entity type 'IdentityUserRole' requires a primary key to be defined.**

I've already find the most preferred solution that i have to use base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);. But as you can see in my code i use that already.

I hope someone has an idea why this error is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you likely resolved the issue already but I had the same problem and resolved it by specifying HasNoKey() on the entity.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(entity => 
{
    entity.HasNoKey();
    entity.HasData(UserRoles);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well. I wanted to keep the primary key that comes with the table by default. Not sure if you are doing a code first or a database first approach but I found with the later this error pops up. Simple solution is to comment out DbSets and OnModelCreating, run the migration, run the database update, then un-comment everything. Hope this helps someone down the road.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).